# How to open files in sublime 2 without having comments folded?

Tags: sublimetext2

Every time I open an exisiting file in sublime, all comments, both lines and blocks, are folded. How can I avoid this?

[image: collapsed definitions]

Comment: Have you installed any packages which maintain your personal settings?

Comment: @AGS No, almost no packages are installed. Just some linting and code completion packages.